# Handling the case when you have missed a turn in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on an Android navigation application for blind people. So naturally no use of displaying map on the screen. My code for now gets the path by building an url and then parsing the html document. I want to make this live i.e. i want to handle the case when he/she goes off the path or goes in the wrong direction, i want my app to alert him.

Is such a thing possible using a Google Maps feature? If possible please give details about that feature or if no such feature exists then is it possible to use existing feature and use it in some way to help solve the problem.

This is my present code:

```
public class GPSTracking extends Activity implements
        TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
{

    protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH_start = 1;
    protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH_end = 2;
    protected static final int RESTART_ALL = 3;
    //total distance travelled till last turn
    Float totalDistance;
    //distance to be travelled from present point to the next point
    Float obtainedDistance;
    //upper button
    Button btnShowLocation;
    //bottom button
    Button btnShowLocationNo;
    //to narate what user should do. 
    TextToSpeech tts;
    //used to get name of current location
    Geocoder geocoder;
    //used to find positioning feature
    GPS gps;
    //start and position of the journey
    String startPosition=null, endPosition=null;
    //strings containing the path.
    String[] string = null;
    //vibrate the mobile
    Vibrator viberator;
    //indexing the present value of string which contains the path
    int i = 0;
    //to maintain proper order of events
    int steps=0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //button on top
        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trueButton);
        //button on the lower side
        btnShowLocationNo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.falseButton);
        //initialising the text to speech
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        //initialising the vibrator.
        viberator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        //to know what the current location
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //to avoid start of multiple threads
            boolean mytaskStarted=false;
            String str=null;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(steps==0){
                    //to make sure values are reset
                    totalDistance=(float)0;
                    obtainedDistance=(float)0;
                    mytaskStarted=false;
                    string=null;
                    str=null;
                    i=0;                    
                    //only ask for initial position if not set
                    if(startPosition == null){
                        speakOut("Please enter the start position");
                        //takes the input using speech to text
                        intentGenerator(RESULT_SPEECH_start);
                    }
                    else{
                        //to enter the destination
                        speakOut("press the button again");
                        steps=1;
                    }
                }
                else if(steps==1){
                    //to enter the destination
                    speakOut("Please enter the destination");
                    intentGenerator(RESULT_SPEECH_end);
                }
                else if(steps==2){
                    //for a impatient user
                    speakOut("please wait");
                    //to avoid start of many asynchronous task
                    if(!mytaskStarted){
                        mytaskStarted=true;
                        //asynchronous task to find the path to be followed
                        new GetPath().execute();
                    }
                }
                else if(steps==3){
                    if (string != null && i < string.length) {
                        if(gps!=null && gps.isGpsEnabled()){
                            speakOut(i + 1 + " " + string[i]);
                            if(i>0 && i<string.length-1 && (string[i]+" ").lastIndexOf(" m ")>-1){
                                str=(string[i]+" ").substring(0,(string[i]+" ").lastIndexOf(" m ")+3);
                                obtainedDistance=Float.parseFloat(str.substring(1+str.substring(0,str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf(" ")).lastIndexOf(" ")).lastIndexOf(" "),str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf(" ")).lastIndexOf(" ")));
                                //increment only when present distance greater than distance in present string so that one will know when to turn.
                                if(((totalDistance+obtainedDistance)-gps.getApprximateDistance())<10)
                                {
                                    i++;
                                    totalDistance=totalDistance+obtainedDistance;
                                }
                            }
                            else if(i>0 && i<string.length-1 && (string[i]+" ").lastIndexOf(" km ")>-1){
                                str=(string[i]+" ").substring(0,(string[i]+" ").lastIndexOf(" km ")+4);
                                obtainedDistance=Float.parseFloat(str.substring(1+str.substring(0,str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf(" ")).lastIndexOf(" ")).lastIndexOf(" "),str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf(" ")).lastIndexOf(" ")));    
                                obtainedDistance*=1000;
                                //increment only when present distance greater than distance in present string so that one will know when to turn.
                                if(((totalDistance+obtainedDistance)-gps.getApprximateDistance())<10)
                                {
                                    i++;
                                    totalDistance=totalDistance+obtainedDistance;
                                }
                            }
                            else if(i==0 ){
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                        else if(gps!=null){
                            gps.resetDistance();
                            gps.stopUsingGPS();
                            //if gps not working.
                            speakOut(i + 1 + " " + string[i]);
                            i++;
                        }
                        else{
                            speakOut(i + 1 + " " + string[i]);
                            i++;
                        }
                    } else if (string != null &&  i >= string.length) {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

        });
        //to get present location
        btnShowLocation.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if(gps==null){
                gps = new GPS(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);
            }
            if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());                 
                try {
                    //obtain the address of present location 
                    List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    if(null!=listAddresses&&listAddresses.size()>0){
                        if (listAddresses.size() > 0) {
                            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                            for(int i = 0; i < listAddresses.size(); i++){
                                Address address =  listAddresses.get(i);
                                int maxIndex = address.getMaxAddressLineIndex();
                                for (int x = 0; x <= maxIndex; x++ ){
                                    if(address.getAddressLine(x)!=null){
                                        result.append(address.getAddressLine(x));
                                        result.append(",");
                                    }
                                }
                                if(address.getLocality()!=null){
                                    result.append(address.getLocality());
                                    result.append("\n\n");
                                }
                            }
                            //if position accurate
                           if(gps.isGpsEnabled()){
                               speakOut(result.toString()+" is Your current location");
                               startPosition=result.toString();
                               Toast.makeText(
                                        getApplicationContext(),startPosition,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           } else if(gps.isNetworkEnabled()){
                               speakOut(result.toString()+" is Your current approximate location. You have to give input of your present location on your own.");
                               Toast.makeText(
                                        getApplicationContext(),result.toString(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
                startPosition=null;
                speakOut(" please turn on gps");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
        //to know what the previous direction string
        btnShowLocationNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int j=0;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(string!=null && j<string.length){
                    speakOut(j + 1 + " " + string[j]);
                    j++;
                }
                else if(string!=null && j>=string.length){
                    j=0;
                }
            }
        });
        //to reset all values for fresh start
        btnShowLocationNo.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                speakOut("Values reset");
                steps=0;
                string=null;
                i=0;
                startPosition=null;
                gps.stopUsingGPS();
                gps=null;
                endPosition=null;
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    //function to handle he text obtained from speech to text.
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
        //set the start 
        case RESULT_SPEECH_start:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> text = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text.get(0),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startPosition = text.get(0);
                steps=1;
                //speakOut("please press button again");

            }
            else{
                steps=0;
            }
            break;
            //to set the end
        case RESULT_SPEECH_end:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> text = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text.get(0),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                endPosition = text.get(0);              
                steps=2;
            }
            else{
                steps=1;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    //function to generate intent to take speech input
    public void intentGenerator(int code) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, code);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Opps! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            speakOut("Opps! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text");
        }
    }
    //mobile gives instruction.
    private void speakOut(String text) {
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        while (tts.isSpeaking()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    //asynchronous task to get the path. THIS IS USED TO AVOID OVERLOAD THE MAIN THRED AND AVOID FORCE CLOSE OF THE APPLICATION
    private class GetPath extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override 
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                string=null;
                String html="";
                //forming url
                URL net = new URL(("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+startPosition+" &daddr= "+endPosition).replaceAll(" ","%20"));
                URLConnection netConnection = null;
                netConnection = net.openConnection();
                //to take the input from google maps
                BufferedReader in = null;
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(netConnection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    html+=inputLine;
                }
                //jsoup parser to parse the document obtained from google maps
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
                //obtain necessary part of the document
                Elements el = doc.getElementsByClass("dir-mrgnr");
                //to remove html tags
                String str = el.text();
                str = str.replaceAll("[0-9]+[.] ", "\n");
                string = str.split("\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //so that on press of button again mobile can read the directions to users  
            steps=3;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //shutdown
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        gps = new GPS(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        if(gps!=null){
            gps.stopUsingGPS();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        //initialising the text to speech  
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
            } else {
                btnShowLocation.setEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi - where does your GPS class come from?

Comment: its coustomised gps class from android hive http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question - how did you implement the `gps.getApprximateDistance()` function? I don't see it in the link provided.